# SignalR 2.0 Timeout Connection

Tags: asp.net, timeout, signalr

I am using SignalR.But there is a problem about timeout.

Timeout disappears after a few minutes and does not work.

How can i **set timeout Connection in SignalR 2.0** ?

Comment: The same question,anybody ..

Comment: Same question... i need to set Timout for Both: connection start, if  take long , ... or on method call, if it take long before it detect that it cant reach server...

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following configuration in your Owin Startup class.

```
        // Make long polling connections wait a maximum of 110 seconds for a
        // response. When that time expires, trigger a timeout command and
        // make the client reconnect.
        GlobalHost.Configuration.ConnectionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40);
        // Wait a maximum of 30 seconds after a transport connection is lost
        // before raising the Disconnected event to terminate the SignalR connection.
        GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        // For transports other than long polling, send a keepalive packet every
        // 10 seconds. 
        // This value must be no more than 1/3 of the DisconnectTimeout value.
        GlobalHost.Configuration.KeepAlive = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        //Setting up the message buffer size
        GlobalHost.Configuration.DefaultMessageBufferSize = 500;
```

Also when you want to keep your client connected to server all the time, you can try to connect it in disconnect hub event.

```
var tryingToReconnect = false;
$.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
                //TODO: write the logic to reconnect to server.
                if(!tryingToReconnect) {
                    // notifyclient about disconnection
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $.connection.hub.start();
                    }, 5000); // Restart connection after 5 seconds.
                }
            });
           $.connection.hub.reconnecting(function() {
                tryingToReconnect = true;
                console.log("reconnecting...");
            });
            $.connection.hub.reconnected(function() {
                tryingToReconnect = false;
                console.log("Reconnected");
            });
```

Comment: There is behavior in the newer 2.3.0 version where you must set the ConnectionTimeout/KeepAlive AFTER you call RunSignalR( ).  If you set it beforehand, it will be overwritten with the default values.

Comment: I am using UWP and it's showing me that  GlobalHost.Configuration property is read only. It has getter but not setter. Could you please guide me on how to pass the configuration?