# SignalR: Value cannot be null, parameter name: s

Tags: signalr

I have a quite simple SignalR application which works locally, but fails to load data when deployed to our production environment.

Here's the sequence of requests made upon page load (all `GET` requests):

```
<app root>                                              200         document    3.9 KB  2.02 s  
before?v=aouETsYNiw4bnMn0RnzIytKnjAOu8acJr3MpfMJz-SM1   200         stylesheet  2.5 KB  58 ms   
after?v=Cv-lJK82snhp2-MwHnIVee8Cx24YmVhR0dcLmnhweHc1    200         script      220 KB  342 ms  
negotiate?connectionData=%5B%7B%22name...               200         xhr         704 B   77 ms   
connect?transport=serverSentEvents&con...               (failed)    eventsource 593 B   2.1 min
```

The `before` and `after` requests are style and script bundles, respectively. The last two urls are truncated to make the table fit; here they are in full:

```
negotiate?connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22builds%22%7D%5D&clientProtocol=1.3&_=1454056625582   
connect?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken=6lFEhj6WReyyEc%2BYmsTAX3%2Fi4EA5KzOR6SaLY0JwfjFMJHq0uYMrKOv4rF7Va1sswGcFce3wKQ5XhhwUMP6Oot8iDx%2Fo24SMnRJXEim2dPmFtmcLqTksRwGeSHf26z5Xw3nLUX19%2BoW4s7kJSXLPRQ%3D%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22builds%22%7D%5D&tid=5
```

Url decoding the `connectionData` parameter yields `[{"name":"builds"}]`, which seems correct since `builds` is the correct name of the only hub I've configured on the server side.

As you see in the log, the last request of these takes over two minutes to report a status, and then simply says "failed". If I right-click it in the debugger and choose "open in new tab", I get (without the delay) a Yellow Screen Of Death stating the following error:

> Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: s
>
> ```
> [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: s]
>     System.IO.StringReader..ctor(String s) +14275218
>     Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Json.JsonSerializerExtensions.Parse(JsonSerializer serializer, String json) +74   
>     Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubRequestParser.Parse(String data, JsonSerializer serializer) +28   
>     Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.OnReceived(IRequest request, String connectionId, String data) +85   
>     Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.<>c__DisplayClassc.<ProcessRequest>b__7() +42
>     Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.FromMethod(Func`1 func) +64  
>     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +144   
>     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +84   
>     Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.<ProcessSendRequest>d__10.MoveNext() +655
>     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +144   
>     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +84
>     Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +827
>     System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32   
>     Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar) +208   
>     System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +434
>     System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
> ```

Searching for this error I get a few hits suggesting that I have permissions problems on the server, but I have given `Everyone` full access rights to the application folder, with no change in behavior. It works locally, but not on the server (even if browsing to `localhost` from the server).

What else should I try?

---

Update: thanks to some guidance from JF Beaulieu in the comments, I have now gotten to the next step. Unlike what I posted in the comments, the request does actually return after a very long time (between 2 and 3 minutes) and is then immediately sent again (and again taking 2-3 minutes to respond). The headers and content of the requests are these:

```
Request URL:https://my.domain.name/signalr/poll?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=A64ByteEncodedString&messageId=d-EC6B29D5-B%2C0%7CC%2C0%7CD%2C0%7CE%2C0%7CF%2C0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22builds%22%7D%5D&tid=6&callback=jQuery2110622865846613422_1454336540065&_=1454336540071
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:192.168.16.243:443

Request Headers
Accept:text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Authorization:Negotiate AVeryLongTokenString
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
DNT:1
Host:my.domain.name
Referer:https://my.domain.name/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Query String Parameters
view source
view URL encoded
transport:longPolling
connectionToken:A64BitEncodedString
messageId:d-EC6B29D5-B,0|C,0|D,0|E,0|F,0
connectionData:[{"name":"builds"}]
tid:6
callback:jQuery2110622865846613422_1454336540065
_:1454336540071

Response Headers
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Type:application/javascript; charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 01 Feb 2016 14:33:35 GMT
Expires:-1
Persistent-Auth:true
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET

Response Content
jQuery2110622865846613422_1454336540065({"C":"d-8D14CCD4-B,0|C,0|D,0|E,0|F,0","M":[]});
```

Comment: Did you made sure you are using Cors? http://forums.asp.net/t/2033309.aspx?Calling+SignalR+hub+from+other+domain+via+CORS

Comment: @JFBeaulieu: I activated cors now as suggested in the post you linked, but it didn't solve the problem. (It did change the behavior, though: I now get a request to `send?transport=longPolling&...` that returns 200 after 2.5 minutes, and a request to `poll?transport=longPolling&...` that seemingly never returns...)

Comment: So we have solved the first problem, now could you please paste in the request and response headers from the Network tab of Chrome dev tools (F12) for that request that never returns

Comment: @JFBeaulieu: Thanks for helping me out here! I've updated the post with the information about the request.

Comment: At first glance, it would seem that you are connected using `longPolling` as transport. It's one of the last resorts that SignalR uses to establish a connection, which would probably explain the long response time. Now you can try to open the url of your hub and see if you get some javascript: `https://my.domain.name/signalr/hubs`

Comment: Yup, a JS response is returned almost instantly.

Comment: That means that you have a connection! The only problem is that you have the worst kind of transport available. Glad this solved the problem

Comment: "Solved the problem" is not quite what I'd call it (yet), as I still don't get any messages from the server and nothing seems to work :) The slow request does repeat a couple of times, always with response times in the order of a couple of minutes, and then starts erroring out with a timeout after 9 minutes. So something is definitely off...

Comment: Make sure that you are using IIS 8.0+ and that WebSockets are installed using  "Turn Windows features on or off" -> Internet Information Services ->World Wide Web Services -> Application Development Features -> WebSocket Protocol

Comment: You could try to manage disconnections using SignalR. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496509/signalr-2-0-timeout-connection

Comment: I am also getting the same error on prod, while same is working on local servers, In my case signalR javascript client is able to connect to Hub using Server-sent events (sse) protocol, but when we connect hub from .Net client using proxy then getting the same error. My .Net client and SignalR hub are hosted as different application under default website on the same server.